# Why i get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut getLogging

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I get this exception on the title. I give some code following:

```
@Component("student")
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void printSomething() {
//        get logging with aop
        System.out.println("student printed something");
//        get logging with aop
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class StudentLogging {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentLogging.class.getName());

    @Pointcut("execution(* aspectorientedprog.aopexample.Student.printSomething(..))")
    private void getLogging() {

    }

    @Around("getLogging()")
    public String aroundPrintSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("before printing something");
        Object o = joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.info("after printing something");
        return o.toString();
    }

}

public class AspectStudentTest {

    @Test
    public void aspect_student_test() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aspect/aspect-conf.xml");
        Student student = context.getBean("student", Student.class);
        student.printSomething();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

my configuration file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="aspectorientedprog"/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

I research something about this error, but all solutions are not worked, it was about AOP version. if i use only

> @Around(execution("class"))

it is working truly but if i use the `@Pointcut and @Around` like above i got this problem...

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* aspectorientedprog.aopexample.Student.printSomething(..))")
    public void getLogging() {

    }
```

Comment: not working with public access modifier, we block to access to @Pointcut mothod already with private